# javascript array member of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I would like to create in javascript an object that contains an array of other objects.
i.e.

```
var xobj = {
    d: 0,
    e: 0,
    f: 0
};

var topObj = {
    x: [],
    a: 0,
    b: 0,
    c: 0
};

topObj.x[0].d = 1;
topObj.x[0].e = 2;
var xx = topObj.x[0].d + topObj.x[0].e;

console.log( xx );
```

I would like `topObj.x` to be an array of `xobj`.

I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'd' of undefined

Answer (score 3):

You can do that, but you have to populate the array with instances of the object (xobj):

```
topObj.x.push(xobj);
```

Comment: Yeap, that works. I guess I have a follow up question: is there a way to declare an array of objects as a property of another object?

Comment: Yes, you can initialize "x" to some existing array object instead of an empty array.

Comment: After some further testing this does not do exactly what I want. It works on a first element of the array, but all additional elements of the array "x" end up references of the one variable xobj. If I modify one - I modify them all. I would like for array "x" to be an array of different instances of xobj. I.E. if I set topObj.x[1].d = 2; I do not want it to affect [0]. right now it does.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted just the values in the xobj to be appended to the array I would create something like this

```
for (prop in xobj) {
    topObj.x.push(xobj[prop])
}
```